# Chrome: WebCodecs API (aka MediaCodecs) available?

Tags: google-chrome

We have recently enrolled onto Chrome's origin trial for the new WebCodecs API (formerly known as "MediaCodecs"). The origin trial is supposed to start in Chrome 86 (see https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5669293909868544).

Despite that, the corresponding Web APIs (eg., `VideoDecoder`) are not available in the Chrome beta (version 86) and development (version 87) releases. Does anyone know Google's policy as to when features behind an origin trial are actually made available to developers?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it. The WebCodecs API does not (yet?) appear under chrome://flags. However, it can be enabled when invoking Chrome on the command line (Chrome 86+ only). So on Linux, this is:

```
google-chrome-beta --enable-blink-features=WebCodecs
```

Other than that, when putting a site under the respective origin trial, the WebCodecs APIs (eg., `VideoDecoder`) are also automatically exposed.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule it's supposed to come to chrome 86 stable on October 19.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 88 can work out of box now :-)

An example:

[WebCodecs MP4 extraction demo](https://tguilbert-google.github.io/webcodecs/mp4/index.html)